# System boots to initramfs after upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04

Tags: upgrade, raid, 22.04

I upgraded to jammy and now I have problems.

I have two 500G SSDs (sda/sdb) in RAID1 mirror in ASUS BIOS ("promise" RAID, I suspect) and sdc is a physical LSI RAID controller. It's a UEFI system, so there were two partitions on the mapper. Upon initial reboot after upgrade, I got "unable to mount root fs" kernel panic. When I rebooted and selected a previous kernel, I got "mdadm no arrays found" error and dropped to initramfs. I don't know why mdadm is being called, as I stated above was using the ASUS BIOS RAID.

I used the boot repair tool, and that also downloaded the mdadm utilities. I've uploaded the repair tool results here:

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/yTb4gZcWc3

Any help getting back to a working system would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm in the same boat. I will start by saying I really have no idea what I'm doing. After upgrading to 22.04, it drops to initramfs because it can't find the hardware/bios raid volume. Using a usb stick image, I can find the raid and mount it and get to the data. Still trying... but at least part of the puzzle is here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Initramfs A complete guess is that it needs some module (mdadm?) to find the raid that is provided by hardware, and that is not loaded yet. Still looking.

Comment: I believe this is related to something like this:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1313169

Comment: I installed ubuntu 22.04 (budgie) for the first time and it stuck at kernel panic, it boots correctly on the usb, so I decided to try version 21.10 first and it works perfectly till now, I'm not sure if I should upgrade to 22.04 using the software update, it seems there are issues with many people, [this is the error screen I saw after installing 22.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDxcv.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue but only /home was on the RAID so this solution may not work for you.

I started with the suggestion from ascii above (bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1313169).  In addition to the steps mentioned, I updated /etc/fstab to use the UUID of the RAID volume instead of the /dev/mapper path.

Then I followed the steps at
https://superuser.com/questions/1221023/isw-raid-member-intel-rapid-storage-on-debian

From busybox:

1. `dmsetup ls` should show the RAID block device (something like isw_bcegjbdfjj_Volume_0000)
2. `partprobe /dev/mapper/[RAID name]` should mount the partitions in /dev/mapper
3. `mount [mountpoint]` should now work if the partition naming is consistent with /etc/fstab
4. If that works, exiting busybox should reboot as normal.