# initramfs shell after upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 - raid

Tags: 22.04, raid, lvm, initramfs, busybox

I upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04 and after reboot I get the following screen / errors (see screenshot) and it goes to the initramfs shell. It's a RAID system. It might be that boot partition was too full during upgrade, or that when freeing space pre-upgrade I deleted too much (and wrongly) from the boot folder. In the Grub menu there's two kernels to choose from (generic and low-latency variant) but none of them work, all revert to initramfs shell.

Problem sounds similar to: [System boots to initramfs after upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405817/system-boots-to-initramfs-after-upgrade-from-21-10-to-22-04)
"dmsetup ls" shows indeed the block devices (see screenshot) but partprobe is not found. **EDIT:** I managed to mount the partitions when booting into a Live USB. But still don't know how to make the system boot.

Can someone provide advice please? I'm pretty lost here... what other information do I have to provide to debug this properly?

Thanks in advance[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It's better to boot into a live USB, backing up your files, wiping and reinstalling ubuntu.

Comment: Better in what respect? I don't fancy wiping all my installed software + configuration, I'd rather just fix this. System was working smoothly before upgrading to 22.04.

Comment: Most likely it's a broken install... And the only way to repair is from a Live USB.